# How to use Clonezilla + NAS to enable an Ubuntu server to clone itself only via remote access?

Tags: backup, nfs, remote-access, disk-image, clonezilla

Is this ***(or something like it)*** feasible, and if so, what high-level procedure/config is needed to do it?

**The rig/setup**

1. Ubuntu Server 20.04 `node1` has only one disk, which can be partitioned.
2. Ubuntu is installed on `node1:/partition1`, and the `node1`'s disk has sufficient freespace on its disk for #2 (below).
3. Install bootable Clonezilla on `node1:/partition2`.
4. `nfs2` is a NFSv4 server ethernet-connected to `node1` and can house the Clonezilla backups.

**The scenario**

When running Ubuntu on `node1:/partition1`: how can one get `node1` to reboot from `/partition2` (Clonezilla) in order to backup/restore `/partition1` (Ubuntu) to/from `nfs2`, then reboot back to Ubuntu (on `/partition1`), without one needing to be physically present with the hardware?

Consider it a "dual boot" rig of Ubuntu + Clonezilla, I suppose.

**The limitations**

I have not yet seen this scenario described in any of the numerous Clonezilla-related blogs/articles/forums/docs I've seen thus far.

All the Clonezilla Live examples I've seen thus far describe an external device (eg: USB thumbdrive) which requires BIOS-boot-changing control, which is not remote-access feasible for my current datacenter.

Separately, the [Clonezilla-dedicated-server rig](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE/), if I'm understanding it correctly, is also not near-term feasible for our environment.

Rather: I'd prefer the above rig, where one can change grub (or whatever the state-of-the-art bootmanager is nowadays) from ssh login to the Ubuntu partition to enable a one-time boot from a/the installed (on the disk) Clonezilla partition, and a successive system restart reboots to the Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

I've the found following procedures, which I'm investigating now. Suggestions, comments welcome.

1. [Clonezilla Live on Hard Drive](https://clonezilla.org/livehd.php)
2. [HOWTO - Starting clonezilla in batchmode from local hard drive with a custom-ocs (automated backup of hard drive)](https://clonezilla.org/related-articles/008_Batch_mode_Clonezilla_on_hard_drive/file/HOWTO-clonezilla-live-hard-drive.htm)